# grep not print any data with my regular expression

Tags: regex, grep

```
egrep -rain "s([1-3]?)=(xf|bf|yf|qz|h|b|hf)(ll|lc|ym|xr)*" *
```

I want to find text like this `s1=xfll2026t` or `s=bflc42428` in follow text.

```
@A
『我的女儿已经长这么大了啊…女大十八变，我都快要认不出了。』[w]
;【立绘bfll164】
@立绘1 s=bfll164
@B
```

But grep return nothing to me.

If I create a new file contian these text, it can be found.  But it cannot be found in my old files.

They are cp936 and dos style. But if I run `grep -rn "xfll" *`, it can be run.

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu with `egrep`. Try to run `grep -Prain` - it should be the same though, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I convert the fileencoding to utf-8 and then run grep.